# Optimizing code for creation of ML dataset

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, pyspark

I'm a statistician, working on a problem with predicting vessel destinations. My current problem is that my code is ***slooow***, and since I am not that great at programming, I find it quite hard to see how to optimize my functions.

Below is the head of the Pandas dataframe which I will perform the operations on.

```
index   imo     fromporta toportb   trajectory                             trajectory_length    voyage_id
0       8005025 port1 port2 [(23, 59.8133333, 2022-02-11 23:53:...)]        9                   1
1       8005025 port1 port2 [(23.425, 59.81333, 2022-02-11 23:53:...)]      18                  1
2       8005025 port1 port2[(23.425, 59.813333, 2022-02-11 23:53:...)]      27                  1
3       4252666 port3 port2 [(17.63, 83.38, 2022-03-08 23:51:45), (1...)]   13                  2
4       4252666 port3 port2[(17.63, 83.38, 2022-03-08 23:51:45), (1...)]    26                  2
```

**Brief explanation**

- imo: ship label(int)
- fromporta: departure port(string)
- toportb: arrival port(string)
- trajectory: List of tuples where each tuple is a (lat, lon, timestamp)
- voyage_id: Int assigned to a unique voyage

As you can see, the voyages are split up into incomplete trajectories, this is for the later prediction.

My output should be a similar dataframe as above, looking like this:

```
index   imo     fromporta toportb traj_length pred_toportb predicted_traj_length similarity(distance)   voyage_id
0       8005025 port1    port2       9               port75                    18           56.7     1
1       8005025 port1    port2       18              port80                    31           41.4    1
2       8005025 port1    port2       27              port2                     25           1.5     1
3       4252666 port3    port2       13              port5                     10           101.51    2 
4       4252666 port3    port2       26              port7                     18           65.6     2
```

I compare each voyage with all other voyages leaving from the same port(except the ones with the same voyage_id), and the calculate the euclidian SSPD distance(using this library: https://github.com/bguillouet/traj-dist/blob/master/traj_dist):

```
def calculate_fast_sspd_similarity(sampled_voyage, historical_voyage):
 traj1 = np.array([(lat, lon) for lat, lon, timestamp, draught in sampled_voyage])
 traj2 = np.array([(lat, lon) for lat, lon, timestamp, draught in historical_voyage])
 return tdist.sspd(traj1,traj2) #can add spherical here


def find_most_similar(sampled_voyage, historical_voyages, similarity_function):

 similarities = []
 for i, row in historical_voyages.iterrows():
   historical_voyage = row['trajectory']
   sim = similarity_function(sampled_voyage, historical_voyage)
   similarities.append(sim)
   #Choose lowest value
 
 most_similar_index = np.argmin(similarities)

 return most_similar_index, np.min(similarities)        

def similarity_measure1(df, similarity_function):
 """Creates new df with similarity measure for each voyage"""
 result = []
 count=0
 for _, row in df.iterrows():

   count+=1
   sampled_voyage = row['trajectory']
   historical_voyages = df[(df['fromporta'] == row['fromporta']) & (df['voyage_id'] != row['voyage_id'])]
   
   if len(historical_voyages)==0:
     continue
     
   most_similar_index, similarity = find_most_similar(sampled_voyage, historical_voyages, similarity_function)
       
   most_similar = historical_voyages.iloc[most_similar_index]
       
   result.append({
           'imo': row['imo'],
           'fromporta': row['fromporta'], 
           'toportb': row['toportb'],
           'trajectory_length': row['trajectory_length'],
           'predicted_toportb': most_similar['toportb'],
           'predicted_trajectory_length': most_similar['trajectory_length'],
           'similarity': similarity
       })

 result_df = pd.DataFrame(result)
 return result_df
```

And to run it,

simply

```
final_ml_df = similarity_measure1(ml_df, calculate_fast_sspd_similarity)
```

I know that it is a lot to ask, but I would really appreciate some help in optimizing the code.

Ps. A possibility is to use pyspark, since I am working in databricks.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using pyspark depending on the amount of data you are processing. With Pandas and other Python libraries, you are not taking advantage of the distributed aspect of pyspark. With Pandas, all the computing is done usually on the driver and it does not distribute the data between the workers.

It may not be straightforward depending on the functions you want to use. Keep in mind that you can use Vectorized UDFs in pyspark so you can use Pandas functions without losing the parallel aspect of Spark (although this will be slower than native Spark functions).